# If a series of non-negative real numbers converges to zero then all terms are zero

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider a series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ that converges to $0$ and such that $a_n\ge 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Does this imply that necessarily $a_n=0$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$? I know it is true for a finite sum but is it still true for an infinite sum?

Comment: Given those assumptions, for each $m \in \Bbb N,0= \sum a_n \geq a_m \geq 0$.

Comment: Yes: if you had a $k \in \mathbb N$ such that $a_k >0$ then $S_m:= \sum_{n=0}^m a_n \ge a_k >0$ for all $m \ge k$ and then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty = \lim_{m \to \infty} S_m \ge a_k >0$.

Answer (score 2):

Given those assumptions, for each $m \in \Bbb N,$ we have $$a_m \leq a_m + \sum_{n \neq m} a_n = 0.$$

Since $a_m\geq 0$ for each $m\in\mathbb{N}$, this proves $\forall m \in \Bbb N~(a_m=0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it has to imply that.  Given the constraints, the series is non-decreasing.  This implies that if there exists any positive term $a_n$, then the overall series can not converge to any value less than $a_n$.

Comment: I think the OP's question is a bit more subtle...  For example, what if we had a partial sum that evaluates to something of order $1/N$, where $N$ is the upper summand?  Then, the series converges to zero, but perhaps each term in the series is still nonnegative for any fixed $N$.

Comment: @Doug I disagree.  The constraints of the problem guarantee that the sequence of partial sums are non-decreasing.  Further, the constraints of the problem guarantee that if there is any positive term $a_n$, that each subsequent partial sum will be $\geq a_n$.  Such an event would make it impossible for the series to converge to $(0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $\forall n_0\ge 0$

$$\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{n=n_0}^N a_n=0$$

and that $\exists a_i>0$ then

$$\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=i}^N a_n=\lim_{N\to \infty} \left(a_i+\sum_{n=i+1}^N a_n\right)=a_i + 0>0$$

which is a contradiction.